# How to define PropTypes for attribute style in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I want to pass 'style' attribute into my component with use JSX syntax.

```
<InputTextWithValidation id="name" 
                         style={{width:'100%'}} .../>
```

How should I define in  my `InputTextWithValidation` component PropTypes? I tried either as an object or a string, eg.

```
InputTextWithValidation.propTypes = {
         style:PropTypes.object, ...
   }
```

but the result was the same: Warning on Chrome console:

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `style` of type `object` supplied to `InputTextWithValidation`, expected `string`.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are declaring the style prop only one time. Even if I need more code to understand where is the problem I have decided to create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9nf68Lu/) for you.

As you can see the Hello class renders the InputTextWithValidation with the style prop which contains an object:

```
style={{width:'100%', background:'red'}}
```

Check the code below, you can run the code snippet.

```js
class InputTextWithValidation extends React.Component{
 render(){
   return(
     <input id = {this.props.id} style = {this.props.style}/>
    );
  }
}

InputTextWithValidation.propTypes = {
  style:PropTypes.object
}


class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name} <InputTextWithValidation id="name" style={{width:'100%', background:'red'}}/></div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.6.1/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your example is comprehensive.

Comment: Except if you have an array of styles. Incoming styles can be an object or an array of objects. Is there a clean way to account for both those? Like `style: PropTypes.styles,`